# Insert data into SQLite table in the same row

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to insert data in an SQLite database from different places in different columns at a time. When I view the database, each insert takes one row. My databases lookes like this:

[image]

How do I achieve this? Any suggestions?

Comment: You actually want to **UPDATE** the row.

Comment: No i want to insert the column in different condition

Comment: Not sure. What you want to do exactly!

Comment: An INSERT always adds a row. An UPDATE will change the current values in the rows that match a WHERE clause.

Comment: `how to insert data into sqlite table in same row?` - meand you want to **update** the row. Otherwise, simply **insert** a new row.

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert a new row within your database, you need to add the following code into the Java class that manages your SQLite database:

```
public long insertRow(String name, String email)
{
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(rowName, name);
    contentValues.put(rowEmail, email);
    return database.insert(databaseTable, null, contentValues);
}
```

The variable `database` refers to the database you attempting to insert the row. The variable `databaseTable` refers to the table you want to insert the row into. If you are attempting to update an existing column, you need to add the following code into the Java class that manages your database:

```
public boolean updateRow(long id, String name, String email)
{
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(rowName, name);
    contentValues.put(rowEmail, email);
    return database.update(databaseTable, contentValues, rowId + “=” + id, null) > 0;
}
```

In order to call this function, you need to pass the `id` of the row and the desired values to pass in order to update them.